# use result of first query in second query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database

`blog (id, title, body and userid)`

`user (id, username,firstname, lastname and about)`

I want to search content from `blog` table for some keyword and get result of `title`, `body` and `userid`. I want to use `userid` in second table select query. so I can display `name(username)` of blog writer.

Basically I want to use `result(userid)` of first query in second `query(userid to username)`

```
modified after suggestion **help me**
```

I tried suggested answers

I think INNER Join can solve my problem But still It is unsolved

now my code is

```
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT blog.*, user.username FROM blog INNER JOIN user ON
user.id = blog.userid WHERE (title LIKE '%$search%' OR body LIKE '%$search%')");
// try with or without WHERE condition ...and also try with blog.title
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo $row['username'];
echo $row['title'];
echo $row['user.username']; //try also
}
```

But I got nothing can you tell me what is wrong with these codes

### there is any issue about primary key and foreign key

Comment: Please provide some code you have already tried.

Comment: I try to use query with in query like

Comment: use foreign key and inner join

Comment: now I have some codes .... can anybody suggest me what is wrong with these codes

Answer (score 1):

Whey dont you try inner JOIN something as

```
select blog.*, user.username, user.firstname,user.lastname,user.about from blog
inner join user on user.id = blog.userid
```

You can add additional where condition if nneded, in this way you will not need 2 query and only query result set will give you everything.

Comment: thanks sir  one more question   Where condition Can I use like title like keyword otherwise blog.title like

Comment: I tried both    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo $row[3];
    echo $row['username'];
    echo $row['user.username'];  }

Comment: I tried suggested answers

I think INNER Join can solve my problem But still It is unsolved

now my code is 

    include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT blog.*, user.username FROM blog INNER JOIN user ON
    user.id = blog.userid WHERE (title LIKE '%$search%' OR body LIKE '%$search%')");
    // try with or without WHERE condition ...and also try with blog.title
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo $row['username'];
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['user.username']; //try also
    }
But I got nothing can you tell me what is wrong with these codes

Answer (score 0):

**TRY this:**

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user_name", "my_password", "database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$query ="SELECT b.*,u.username from blog as b INNER JOIN user as u ON b.userid= u.id ";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $row['username']." ".$row['title'];
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a join

```
select blog.title,blog.id,user.username,user.firstname,user.lastname,user.about from blog join user on user.id = blog.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get your result by joining of these two tables. Always use joining instead of using subquery / inner query. Below is the query to fetch the desire output:

`select blog.*,user.username,user.firstname,user.lastname from blog JOIN user on blog.userid=user.id;`

```
Table       index
blog        id primary key
blog        userid
user        id primary key
```

For better performance always have index of joining column.

Answer (score -1):

You can use inner join or simple join for the same,also for that you need to have foreign key of user id in blog table for reference

Comment: its the exact answer as the @Abhik 's